# Moving particular items from multiple arrays into new arrays - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-column

I have 3 arrays:

```
$item_name = array( 'Apples', 'Oranges' );
$item_price = array( '29', '39' );
$item_quantity = array( '5', '10' );
```

What I need to do is place each item from the first and second index of each array, into it's own array (I hope that makes sense), here is an example of what I am looking to achieve:

```
$my_array1 = array( 'Apples', '29', '5' );
$my_array2 = array( 'Oranges', '39', '10' );
```

Please note that there may be more items in each array, but every array will have the same number of items.

I am stumped, is there some cheeky PHP array function, that we could use in some strange sort of way to achieve this?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do `item_name`, `item_price` and `item_quantity` will be placed in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this migth work. All arrays need to have the **same length**.

```
$item_name = array( 'Apples', 'Oranges' );
$item_price = array( '29', '39' );
$item_quantity = array( '5', '10' );

$my_arrays = array();

foreach($item_name as $index=>$name){
   $my_arrays[$index] = array($item_name[$index], $item_price[$index], $item_quantity[$index]);
}
```

---

You will have an array `my_arrays` of arrays. These arrays contain the information you need.

```
$my_arrays[0]: ['Apples', '29', '5']
$my_arrays[1]: ['Oranges', '39', '10']
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks so much, that worked for me! Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_column on the combined array, **[live demo](https://eval.in/792937)**.

```
array_column([$item_name, $item_price, $item_quality], 0);
```

Comment: That also works, thanks so much for your answer it's really appreciated. I will look into the array_column function as this will definitely help me again in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$item_name = array( 'Apples', 'Oranges' );
$item_price = array( '29', '39' );
$item_quantity = array( '5', '10' );

$my_arrays = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($item_name);$i++){
$my_arrays[$i][0]=$item_name[$i];
$my_arrays[$i][1]=$item_price[$i];
$my_arrays[$i][2]=$item_quantity[$i];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_arrays);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```